# sudo, Bad substitution, indirect parameter expansion

Tags: shell, unix

Here a script that try to do a 'ifndef' (ifndef.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

################# __ifndef__ #################
MAIN_SCRIPT=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P)"/$(basename $0)"
script_path=$(echo $MAIN_SCRIPT | sed -e "s@/@_@g" -e "s@\.@_@g" -e "s@-@_@")
define_var="ALREADY_SOURCED_$script_path"
echo "Main_script: $MAIN_SCRIPT"
echo "script_path: $script_path"
echo "define_var: $define_var"
echo "??: ${!define_var}"
[[ ! -z ${!define_var} ]] && return
export ALREADY_SOURCED_$script_path="defined"
################# __ifndef__ #################
```

When I try to execute this code in an another file (`main.sh`):

```
. ./ifndef.sh

echo "TEST !"
```

With sudo, I always get this error:

```
./main.sh: 10: ./ifndef.sh: Bad substitution
```

The command I used to launch the script is: `./main.sh`

I don't know why `${!define_var}` is problematic.

Comment: Use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` at top

Comment: Same problem :/

Comment: What command are you using to execute this script?

Comment: Among the obvious bugs here that will be triggered by executing this script with `sh` rather than `bash`, indirect expansions a la `${!foo}` are definitely not part of the POSIX sh standard.

Comment: I updated my description, now I use bash rather than sh

Comment: `${!define_var}` is **not** problematic if your shell is actually bash, and you really have a variable by that name. (You haven't adequately proved, to this point, that you do).

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful if you'd show the actual variable name, so we can validate that it's legal. `/`, `.` and `-` are not the only characters that aren't legal in variable names.

Comment: ...or, better, you could just make `already_sourced` an associative array.

Comment: so, if you're sourcing this as a script, what interpreter is the script you're sourcing it from using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run a bash script with `sh` -- it can only be run with bash. In particular, you're using several features here (including both indirect expansion a la `${!foo}` and the extended test operator `[[ ]]`) that aren't part of the POSIX sh standard, and so aren't guaranteed to be available when run with `sh`.

Instead of running `sh yourscript`, run `bash yourscript` or just `./yourscript` (with a shebang set and execute permissions granted); and instead of starting it with `#!/bin/sh`, start it with `#!/bin/bash`. If this is being sourced, ensure that the script you're sourcing it from is itself started with bash.

---

The other thing here is that your escaping isn't complete enough to ensure that your `$script_path` really is a valid shell variable name. Instead of trying to fix that, just switch to using an associative array -- that ways keys can contain any character other than NUL, which is invalid in UNIX paths anyhow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# uses the first bash interpreter on the PATH, so on MacOS X, can use MacPorts bash
# if sourcing this, be sure to do the same in the script you're sourcing it from.

### start version check
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || {
  echo "Current shell is not bash; must use bash 4.0 or later" >&2
  return 1 || exit 1
}
[[ $BASH_VERSION =~ ^([4-9][.]|[0-9][0-9]+) ]] || {
  echo "Bash version 4 or newer is required (using $BASH_VERSION)" >&2
  return 1 || exit 1
}
### end version check

### start redefinition check
declare -A already_sourced
[[ ${already_sourced[$BASH_SOURCE]} ]] && return
already_sourced[$BASH_SOURCE]=1
### end redefinition check
```

The above requires Bash 4.x, which isn't shipped with MacOS, but is available through [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).

Comment: I updated my description, now I use bash rather than sh

Comment: See answer, updated to provide a cleaner bash-specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using BASH you can skip all `sed` do all the replacements in BASH itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

################# __ifndef__ #################
MAIN_SCRIPT=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P)"/$(basename $0)"
script_path="${MAIN_SCRIPT//[\/.-]/_}"
echo "Main_script: $MAIN_SCRIPT"
echo "script_path: $script_path"
define_var="ALREADY_SOURCED_$script_path"
echo "define_var: $define_var"
echo "??: ${!define_var}"
[[ ! -z ${!define_var} ]] && return
declare -x $define_var="defined"
echo "##: ${!define_var}"
################# __ifndef__ #################
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your sentence 'Using BASH you can skip all sed do all the replacements in BASH itself:'

Comment: You can see I've removed your sed command by `"${MAIN_SCRIPT//[\/.-]/_}"` that is what I meant.

Comment: Fine, I'll try this evening and will come back to you. Thanks again :)

Comment: [This code is running here without any error](http://ideone.com/p755eC), how are you invoking this script?

Comment: Ok, this work finally, but I've another problem :/ See the description

Comment: Yes, everything is ok !

Answer (score 0):

My bad !

I just had to add '#!/bin/bash' in the inner script (main.sh here)

Comment: Since I told you to do that in my answer (in a comment within the code, currently editing that into the text as well), you might consider accepting it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Funny thing is that was my first comment below the question about 19 hours ago :)

Comment: @anubhava, right -- I think the OP took that to mean the shebang of the sourced script (which obvs. doesn't matter except as an indication of intent), as opposed to the shebang of the script doing the sourcing.

Comment: Yes because script doing the sourcing wasn't part of the question then.

Comment: @anubhava, indeed. That said, it was after looking at the intent of their previously-posted code (to handle being sourced) but prior to that edit that I noted that the sourcing script's shebang mattered in a code comment in my answer, which is now part of the general text.